# Cannot implicitly convert type object[] to UnityEngine.GameObject[]

Tags: objects, inheritance

So, I cannot implicitly convert type object[] to UnityEngine.GameObject[]. But why? As far I know, are all types a inheritanced types of object. So, for my logic, I could put a GameObject array in a object array. That's why, this should work:

```
spawnedObjects = FindObjectOfType<Tools> ().AddObjectToArray (spawnedObjects, go);
```

//

```
public object[] AddObjectToArray(object[] _array, object _toAdd){
    if (_array.GetType() == _toAdd.GetType()) {
        object[] a = new object[_array.Length + 1];
        a = _array;
        a [a.Length] = _toAdd;
        return a;
    } else {
        Debug.LogWarning ("The object that should be added to the array have to be the same type as the arrays type. Initially array was retuned!");
        return _array;
    }
}
```

But yeah, it won't do

Comment: The way your question is worded is confusing. Is the error coming from this section of code you posted? If so exactly what line? `object[]` is not the same as Unity's representation of `UnityEngine.GameObject[]`. You make it sound like you are casting `object[]` into something more specific: `UnityEngine.GameObject[]`

Comment: the "spawnedObjects = FindObjectOfType<Tools> ().AddObjectToArray (spawnedObjects, go)" makes the problem

Comment: spawnedObjects is of type GameObject[], correct?

Comment: Are you familiar with generics? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379564(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I cannot implicitly convert type object[] to UnityEngine.GameObject[]. But why?

Because allowing it subverts the type system. Assume want you want is allowed, and then consider this:

```
object[] a = ...;
GameObject[] b = a;
```

Arrays are reference types, so `a` and `b` refer to the same actual array. Now consider if you did:

```
a[1] = new object();
```

This is legal, because `a` is `object[]`. But now `b[1]` is not a `GameObject`, it's a plain `object`. You have broken the type system.

Consequently, you are not permitted to make this implicit cast. It looks like you are *attempting* to prevent this occurrence at runtime in your code, but the compiler doesn't care. The compiler will try, and succeed, in stopping this at compile-time.

---

Why don't you just use `List<GameObject>`? It will let you append new `GameObject`s to the list more efficiently than you're doing by recreating the entire array (and with fewer bugs). For example:

```
List<GameObject> spawnedObjects;

...

spawnedObjects.Add(go);
```

Comment: Ahh, I understand the whole problem. Thank you :) 

Comment: I wanted to try something different this time

Comment: Sure, that's fair, but what you have is slower, less memory efficient, and will crash since you access an array out of bound ("a[a.Length]" isn't safe)